# Compare 2 products output all difference

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Is it possible to compare using product id in phpmyadmin so after running in mysql it will output any differences between a product id which has been resaved and showing on front end and another which is not - to show exactly what settings and attributes and everything internal as well

Basically, I want to know what difference is for example Product entity_id 1 and entity_id 2 --- from all the tables in the same one database -anything product A has which product B doesn not and any table Product A belongs to and Product B doesnt

Comment: Basically I want to know what difference is for example Product entity_id 1 and entity_id 2   --- from all the tables in the same one database -anything product A has which product B doesn not and any table Product A belongs to and Product B doesnt -

Comment: Provide us with a `SELECT` that will display all the attributes of a "product".  With that, we may be able to show you how to get the 'difference'.

Comment: I'd recommend you to show source table(s) DDL, some example data (in INSERT INTO form), and desured result for that data.

Comment: Just to clarify for this purpose I dont have any expected result or know exactly what tables to call for - I want to run a query to get me all tables and columns settings associated with 2 products do a blind search